# Convert List<HashMap<String, Object>> to stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of this type `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` ResultSet that contains the result of a query to a database. 
I wanted call stream() on the List object. How do I do that ?
This code create my list:

```
public class ResultSetToMap {
    int Columns = 0;
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();

    public List ResultSetToMap(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            row = new HashMap<String, Object>(columns);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
                row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
            }
            list.add(row);
        }
        return list;

    }
}
```

I can query the list data in this way:

```
for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And I want to make queries about those data later. Of the type:

```
films.stream()
    .filter(Film.LENGTH.greaterThan(60))
    .sorted(Film.TITLE)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Where is the List in your example code? You are only iterating over one item. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: *"I wanted to make this list a stream"* Call `stream()` on the `List` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the fact that you should better filter and sort your data in your SQL you should use an Object `Film` instead of a `Map`:

```
public class Film {
    private String title;
    private int length;
    // more attributes if you have ...

    public Film(String title, int length) {
        this.title = title;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + " : " + length;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this while creating the result List:

```
public List<Film> getFilmsFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Film> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        result.add(new Film(rs.getString("TITLE"), rs.getInt("LENGTH")));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use the column names from your table in the `rs.getInt()` and `rs.getString()` methods.

Use your `getFilmsFromResultSet()` methos like this:

```
List<Film> films = getFilmsFromResultSet(rs);
films.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getLength() > 60)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Film::getTitle))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: If you add a `toString()` method to `Film`, you could keep the `forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: @Andreas Yes that's correct, I added that part now.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `flatMap` operation like:

```
list.stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Although the question *could* be interpreted to be asking for this, it doesn't make a lot of sense. The maps in the list are rows, with column name as the map key, so flatmapping each name/value pair is not what is needed, especially given the desired `filter`, `sorted`, `forEach` chain shown at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You stream a list by calling `stream()` on the `List` object.

Example:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(row -> ((Number) row.get("LENGTH")).intValue() > 60)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(row -> (String) row.get("TITLE")))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that it would be better to build a list of objects representing the row data, instead of a list of maps, so the data can be handled in a type-safe manner.

Comment: How do I make this exchange? To create a list of objects?

Comment: @programmer See [answer by Samuel Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479564/5221149).